# C++ Error LNK 1120 about TEMPLATES

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “unresolved external symbol” errors when using templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates)
>   [Link error using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550219/link-error-using-templates)

I hava a template class 'MyHeap' in two files 'MyHeap.h' and 'MyHeap.cpp'. Compile in vs10, ok. but when I try to use this class in main, this error happened. I looked around, still can't solve this myself. please help me...

Error Info >>

```
MyHeap<int> minHeap(MyHeap<int>::MaxHeap);
```

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyHeap::MyHeap(enum MyHeap::HeapType)" (??0?$MyHeap@H@@QAE@W4HeapType@0@@Z)    D:\文档\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C++\ConsoleCPP_Trivia\ConsoleCPP_Trivia\program.obj
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\文档\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C++\ConsoleCPP_Trivia\Debug\ConsoleCPP_Trivia.exe

```
MyHeap.h:
-----------------------------------------------------------
#pragma once

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyHeap
{
public:
    static enum HeapType {CustomizedHeap, MaxHeap, MinHeap};

private:
    typedef bool (*COMP_FUNC)(const T&, const T&);
    COMP_FUNC _comp;
    HeapType _heapType;
    vector<T> _data;

public:
    MyHeap(HeapType heap_type = MaxHeap);
    MyHeap(COMP_FUNC compare_function);

    void add(const T& item);    
    T remove();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void clear();

private:
    bool __compare(const T&, const T&);
};
```

Comment: -1: Possibly the most asked question on SO related to C++.

Answer (score 3):

Templates must be defined in the header files. You cannot separate implementation of template classes/functions in source and header files.

The reason is, that templates are compile-time "feature" of C++ and their implementations must be visible at compile time.

Comment: You mean that I should put all code in the .h file ?

Comment: @Ggicci Yes, that's what I mean :)